# SQL - Write Query with field names and table name stored in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, while-loop, dynamic-sql

I work for an Insurance Company and creating a custom application. When we apply a coverage to a policy it is stored in a table with a Limit, Deductible, and Premium field.  However, there are many coverages that do not follow the norm.  They use different fields for Limit, Deductible, and Premium and are even stored in different tables.  (Don’t ask why and don’t even try to understand the fact that they are STILL doing this so I need to leave logic to allow for additional coverages like this.)  There is also no rhyme or reason to what fields they choose so varies greatly.

So, we have decided to create “LookUp” tables that will store all the information we need for a coverage.  This avoids numerous joins – we were having issues with speed and performance of the application.

I need to find a way to prepopulate all these fields into a table.  I would like the best option performance-wise.  This will end up being a Nightly job – so when we receive a new snapshot of data we will run this query and prepopulate/update the values of the table.

Here is an example of my table, it contains the Coverage  name (Coverage), the table (File), and the fields for the Limit, Deductible, and Premium.  The PolicyNum field is a concatenation of LOB + Policy + Module.  I need all three of these fields to join to a policy.  I wanted to use a table since they will be adding new coverages.  Keep in mind, I created this tables so can add more fields to it.

Here is the create script for my table - I fill it from an Excel spreadsheet so made all the fields nVarChar(255) in order for that process to run smoothly:

```
USE [PolicySummary]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Coverage](
    [CoverageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LOB] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Coverage] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [File] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Limit] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Deductible] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Premium] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [IsMultLimit] [bit] NULL,
    [IsMultDeductible] [bit] NULL,
    [IsMultPremium] [bit] NULL,
    [InsuranceLine] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PolicyNum] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Coverage] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [CoverageID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

So in a nutshell, a policy may have the coverage BP0713.  I then to look at this table and see that I need to run the following query:
    SELECT BYAGVA as limit, BYPPTX as Deductible, BYA3VA as Premium FROM ASBYCPP WHERE BYARTX+BYASTX+BYADNB = @PolNum

The table contains the table name, the 3 fields, and the concatenation for the Policy Number.

Currently, I am looping through each coverage in a policy and selecting the values one at a time in a WHLIE Loop.  Works but it is slow and I am hitting the query numerous times just to open the app (numerous units per policy so will be ran for each unit).

```
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @Limit=' + ISNULL(Limit, '''''') + N',@Deductible=' +     ISNULL(Deductible, '''''') + N',@Premium=' + ISNULL(Premium, '''''') + N' FROM PHI_PIJ.dbo.'     + [File] + N' WHERE ' + PolicyNum + N' = ''' + @PolNum +'''' + N' AND ' + @CovField +     N'='''+Coverage +''''
FROM PolicySummary.dbo.Coverage 
WHERE Coverage = @Coverage 
AND LOB = @LOB           

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Limit nVarChar(255) output,@Deductible nVarChar(255)         output,@Premium nVarChar(255) output', @Limit output, @Deductible output, @Premium output

INSERT INTO #OptCov2 VALUES(@Coverage, @Description, @LOB, @Limit, @Deductible,     @Premium)
```

Can I get help with finding a way to populate my “Lookup” table each night so all I would have to do is 
    SELECT Limit, Deductible, PREMIUM FROM CoverageLookUp WHERE PolicyNum = @PolicyNum

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Here’s what I’ve got so far.  It takes nearly 4 minutes to run the top 1000 records and there are a total of 614,497 records to run.

```
SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT @Limit=' + ISNULL(Limit, '''''') + N',@Deductible=' +   ISNULL(Deductible, '''''') + N',@Premium=' + ISNULL(Premium, '''''') + N'     FROM PHI_PIJ.dbo.ASBYCPP' + N' WHERE ' + PolicyNum + N' = ''' + @PolicyKey +'''' + N' AND BYAOTX' + N'='''+Coverage +''''
FROM PolicySummary.dbo.Coverage 
WHERE Coverage = @Coverage 
AND LOB = 'BOP'         

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Limit nVarChar(255) output,@Deductible nVarChar(255) output,@Premium nVarChar(255) output', @Limit output, @Deductible output, @Premium output              

UPDATE PolicySummary.dbo.CoverageLkup
SET Limit = @Limit, Deductible = @Deductible, Premium = @Premium
WHERE CovAbbrev = @Coverage
AND PolicyKey = @PolicyKey
```

Comment: Can you share the schema/layout of the tables you are pulling from?

Comment: I fill the table from an Excel spreadsheet so the easiest way was to make all the fields nVarChar(255)  :)
I attached my Create script for the table above.

Comment: I updated the question to show the code I use so far.  This is the piece inside my LOOP.  It works but is VERY slow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this from the wrong angle. I would state your plan as "creating a mapping table that you use a a dynamic SQL roadmap to your source data." Instead I think you should copy* you source data from the disparate tables into a single master look-up table.

While this will "duplicate" the data it will result in a much more efficient look-ups.

*copy: I originally wrote replicate, but I don't think Replication is the correct technology here. It might be possible, but its not the intended use case for Replication.

You want a different sort ETL, probably very simple jobs or SSIS (or even triggers) that keep your look-up master in sync with all the individual pieces.

Let me know with a comment of that doesn't make sense. Or if I appear to be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is maybe not exactly what you have, but hopefully this points you in the right direction. You definitely want to keep from looping and especially doing that for each policy.

From an ease of update standpoint, I would suggest the following:

Here is your table with the table names and the field names. It will be used to build your select statement. You should only have 1 record per table in here.

```
create table tableref (
  tablename nvarchar(255), 
  lobfield nvarchar(255), 
  policyfield nvarchar(255), 
  modulefield nvarchar(255),
  limitfield nvarchar(255), 
  deductfield nvarchar(255),
  premiumfield nvarchar(255))
```

Now create your select statement to pull all of the data out of the tables from tableref

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '', @unionall nvarchar(50) = ''
select @sql = @sql + @unionall 
    + ' select ' + lobfield + '+' + policyfield + '+' + modulefield + ' as policynumber, ' 
    + limitfield + ' as limit, ' 
    + deductfield + ' as deduct, ' 
    + premiumfield + ' as premium '
    + ' from ' + tablename
  , @unionall = ' union all '
from tableref
```

Last, but not least, insert the records into the lookup table

```
select @sql = 'insert into lookuptable (policynum, limit, deduct, premium) ' + @sql
exec (@sql)
```

To fine tune, add indexes where appropriate. Also, this solution will break after 8000 characters in @sql, so depending on your situation, you might need to break this up.